# how to loop through higher order function?

Tags: jquery, arrays

```
data.forEach(function (object, index) {

    console.debug(object.output);
    //this consists of array object like below
    //how to loop through these using higher order function so that I don't have to use for loop

    [0]{"id": "453", "name":"keren"},
    [1]{"id": "453", "name":"amy"},
    [2]{"id": "453", "name":"samta"}
```

The error I'm getting says, object.output is not a function.
The reason I'm prefer higher order function is to avoid, nested for loop that gets the length of the array and then loop through nested array inside main array.

I also cannot get the length of object.output even if I were to use the traditional for loop.

This is what logged inside :`data.forEach(function (object, index) {....}`

[image]

Now, how do I loop through each object of output?

Edit based on Geeky answwer:

```
data.forEach(function (object, index) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (key){

        if (typeof object[key] == 'object') {
            console.debug(object[key]);
            //how to iterate through each object here?
            object[key].forEach(function(x){
            console.debug(x);
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: is `output` supposed to be a property of the objects you are using? if so, what resource confirms this?

Comment: @SamOnela, 'output' is the object that consist an array of objects

Comment: object.forEach(function(obj){console.log(obj);});This will give you the objects in the array

Comment: have you tried like this for(i = 0 ; i< data.length; i++){ data[i].output }

Comment: @Geeky, object.forEach is not a function(anonymous function)

Comment: This question is too confusing to answer. Please edit it to show your exact input and exact desired output and be as clear as possible.

Comment: @AndyRay, I added picture which shows the hierarchy of object to be looped through

Comment: @Araz, can you show  how to get length of data[i].output?

Comment: you need length of data ... ist array of json objects so it returns the number of objects

Comment: Lets know whats working here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following snippet

```js
var arr=[ {"id": "453", "name":"keren"}
            ,{"id": "453", "name":"amy"}
            ,{"id": "453", "name":"samta"}
            ]

var object={"output":arr}
Traverse(object);

function Traverse(object){
Object.keys(object).forEach(function (key){
    console.log(object[key]);
    if(typeof(object[key])==="object")
           Traverse(object[key]);
         
});
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I've already tried this and doesn't help as it says object.output is not a function..I screenshot the data hierarchy, please refer to my edited post

Comment: I have modified the code please check and confirm if this is what ur looking for

Comment: now can get the objects however, how to further loop through each object of output? please refer my edited post above

Comment: Modified the code ...check and let me know if this is what you are lookign for